# Доступ к переменной через админку wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Установил плагин геотаргетинга с выводом разной информации для разных городов и стран, в php выглядит так:

```
echo do_shortcode("[wt_geotargeting country_show='RU']  Вывод текста для России [/wt_geotargeting]");
```

Предположим, я не хочу писать через шорткод вывод информации, я создаю переменную и помещаю ее в код, выходит так:

```
$block_1 = 'Блок 1';
echo do_shortcode("[wt_geotargeting country_show='RU'] $block_1 [/wt_geotargeting]");
```

Собственно, вопрос - клиенту необходимо самостоятельно менять содержимое переменной (картинки вставлять, текст), как можно получить доступ к переменной через админку?

Comment: Можно создать: 1) дополнительную настройку в настройках темы; 2) опцию, значение которой изменять на отдельной (или уже существующей) странице в админке; 3) метабокс для типа поста или категории, который будет хранить пользовательское поле. Зависит от логики использования этой "переменной".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Костыль костылем будет, но "произвольные поля" можно создать и подставить шоркод в твою переменную. И он с админки будет править и тебе меньше гемороя:DDDD

Comment: Дружище, поделись советом, не знаю уже где искать, мне надо контент разный выводить, в кастомные поля все строкой выводят с массивом

Comment: Advanced Custom Fields: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/; 
ессесно шорт код: <?php echo do_shortcode ('[acf field="title_first(название поля)" post_id="799(айди записи у которой это поле)"]'); ?>
И попробовать сделать таким образом: $block_1 = <?php echo do_shortcode ('[acf field="title_first(название поля)" post_id="799(айди записи у которой это поле)"]'); ?>;
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/ - документация. плюшка - http://wp-book.ru/video-advanced-custom-fields-proizvolnye-polya-i-nastrojki-zapisi-v-wordpress-chast-1/

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает, но с изображениями проблема осталась, т.е если в типе поля выбрать Редактор WYSIWYG, то контент выводит отлично, но если выбрать изображение - то выводит массив с информацией об изображении, пытался вывести через $block['url'] - не выводит

Comment: Не знаю получиться или нет вот такой для редактора есть код, только тогда в редактор нужно закидывать фотки хоть сто тыщь.
<?php if (get_field("redactor имя поля WYSIWYG")) : ?>
  <?php preg_match_all ("/<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*[\"']\/?([^\"']+)[\"'][^>]*\>/", get_field("redactor"), $images);?>
    <?php if (!empty($images[1])) : ?>
      <?php foreach ($images[1] as $img) : ?>
        <div>
          <img src="<?= $img?>" alt=""/>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: если в типе поля выбрать редактор и через "добавить медиафайл" загружать изображения - они выводятся, мне надо именно через тип поля "изображения" их выводить

Comment: вот тут посмотри https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/ 
и смотря сколько изображений нужно или же он может добавить их через админку? если через админку то редактор WYSIWYG и мой код выше, а дивы внутри можешь оформлять как душе угодно

Comment: он может их добавлять через админку, необходимо одно изображение

Comment: тогда thumbnail в помощь <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?> добавить может как "Задать миниатюру"

Comment: чувствую я тебя замучил, но я имел в виду не миниатюру записи, а изображение из кастом поля) т.е в настройках поля я выбираю тип "изображения", в записи в этом поле выбираю картинку, обновляю запись, но на выходе получается строка массива с информацией о картинке, т.е альт, заголовок, адрес, где оно лежит, но само изображение не выводит, пытался вывести его через src img $block[url'], но не вышло, может я неправильно код написал

Comment: тебе в поле Изображение нужно выбрать подпункт "ссылка на изображение" и в свой <img src="<?= get_field("erer название поля", 392 ид записи или страницы); ?>">

Answer (score 0):

В расширенной версии плагина [WT Geotargeting](https://web-technology.biz/cms-wordpress/plugin-wt-geotargeting/) есть возможность удобного редактирования контента закрепленного за городами.

Каждый, добавленный в панели администратора, город является **Произвольным типом записи**, таким образом, с помощью **Произвольных полей** к городам можно прикреплять любой контент, и в дальнейшем выводить его через шорткод [WT_LOCATION](https://web-technology.biz/cms-wordpress/plugin-wt-geotargeting-for-cms-wordpress/shortkod-wt_location-pro/).

Такой подход заметно упрощает администрирование и управление геозависимым контентом.